# Css Div Floating Issue in ExtJs TreePanel Object

Tags: html, css, extjs

I'm using treepanel object in ExtJs and I want to create two div side by side inside treepanel items. Is it possible to set one of them's width fluid and the other's width auto ? Actually, html and css codes work properly but when I put them inside treepanel item's text property it's not working. Where I am doing a mistake ?

Here is a part of my Extjs Code;

```
{
xtype: 'treepanel',
cls: 'wikiTreePanel',
root: {
    text:
    '<div class="treeItemTitleWrapper">'+
        '<div class="countSide"><span>12</span></div>'+ 
        '<div class="titleSide">Main Wiki Title Main Wiki Title Main Wiki Title</div>'+                                         
    '</div>',
    expanded: true,
}}
```

Here is my html and css code;

```css
.treeItemTitleWrapper{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 26px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.treeItemTitleWrapper .titleSide{
    background: orange;
    line-height: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.treeItemTitleWrapper .countSide{
    float: right;
    height: 26px;
    background: pink;
}
```

```html
    <div class="treeItemTitleWrapper">
  <div class="countSide"><span>12121212</span></div>
  <div class="titleSide">Main Wiki Title Main Wiki Title Main Wiki Title Main Wiki Title Main Wiki Title Main Wiki Title Main Wiki Title Main Wiki Title Main Wiki Title</div>           
 </div>
```

[image]

How can I do that. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You input is a little unclear. As per my understanding if you want to reduce the title to few characters, you can use the below method.

```
Ext.util.Format.ellipsis('Custom Title', 6);
```

[Ext.util.Format.ellipsis](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.util.Format.html#method-ellipsis)